# Unity Steam VR loading box

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have replaced the Steam VR loading scene with a Skybox that I created, but when loading in, there is still this floating square Steam VR panel with a few moving bars on it. The loading scene is meant to be scenic so this box really removes that effect. Does anybody know how to remove / disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **SteamVR_LoadLevel** **LoadingScreentexture** property to a texture so it overrides the default texture (there doesn't seem to be a way to select no texture).

Set the SteamVR_LoadLevel Loading Screen Width In Meters to 0

This will render your loading texture at a size of 0 making it look invisible.

The texture you set can probably be super small and single color because you're not going to ever see it.

If you're doing this in code it'll be something like the following:

```
public Texture LoadingScreenTexture;

public void LevelLoader()
{
    var loader = new GameObject("loader").AddComponent<SteamVR_LoadLevel>();

    // Loading progress bar
    loader.loadingScreen = LoadingScreenTexture;

    loader.loadingScreenWidthInMeters = 0;
}
```